# Having the names of the fields, how can I initialize, with blank data, the undefined fields of an object?

Tags: javascript, initialization, undefined, field

In Javascript, I have an array of strings, that represent all the possible names of an object's fields.

```
var fields = ["name", "age", "address"];
```

The server's response is an array of objects that may, or may not, contain all the fields from **fields**.

```
var response = [
  {"name" : "Tom"}, {"name" : "Jenny", "age" : 25}, ...
];
```

I need to populate all the missing fields with a an empty string or something so that there will be no more undefined fields (I can't do this on the server).

So far I have this

```
jQuery(fields).each(function(fieldKey, field){

  jQuery(response).each(function(resultKey, result){

    if (result[field] == undefined) result[field] = "";

  });

});
```

**Is there a better and more efficient way ?**

Comment: What do you mean by undefined. If the textfield is blank, isnt it "" already?

Comment: By undefined I mean that the field (attribute) does not exist in that object. I am not referring to a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof` to check a variable presence.

```
jQuery(fields).each(function(fieldKey, field){
  //fieldKey: index (number); field: array item (string)

  jQuery(response).each(function(resultKey, result){
    //resultKey: index (number); result: array item (object)

    if (typeof result[field] == 'undefined') result[field] = "";

  });

});
```

Comment: I am curious if this is faster than my current solution

Comment: It's theorically slower, yes. But without using `typeof`, the code might cause error and any remaining code within current `try..catch` block (by jQuery) won't be executed. If you want performance, don't use jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery. The following code assumes the response object is present.

```
var fields = ["name", "age", "address"],
    i, j;

// for each response object, check the fields
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    // for each field look if it is present in current response object
    for (j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
        // if not present, create with empty string
        if (typeof response[i][fields[j]] === 'undefined') {
            response[i][fields[j]] = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea but the response is an array of objects. It seems that your solution is for a single object. I may be wrong, though ...

Comment: Corrected with another loop. Note that the standard for(;;)-loop is the fastet way to iterate arrays.

Comment: I changed the .hasOwnProperty() to typeof === 'undefined' for performance reasons. See [link](http://jsperf.com/type-vs-hasownproperty)